# Create a loop that will increment time by one hour

Tags: php, time, strtotime

I've spent so much time on trying to figure out how to create a loop that will echo time between given $start_time and $end_time incrementing it by one hour in format HH:MM.
    For example if i have $start_time = "09:00" and $end_time="15:00" the output should be like:

> 09:00
>
> 10:00
>
> 11:00
>
> 12:00
>
> 13:00
>
> 14:00
>
> 15:00

Any idea how to do it? I know i should use php timestamps and strtotime etc. by i have never used them, so i can't do anything, pls help...

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its been awhile since I've coded PHP but look at this [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php).
*Note I posted this before the Question was edited.*

```
while($starttime < $endtime)
{
    echo $starttime;
    $starttime = date_add($starttime, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 hour'));
}
```

Comment: well that didn't work for me. i've inserted "09:00:00" and "15:00:00"... still thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with mktime()

```
$start = 7;
$end = 15;
for ($time = $start; $time <= $end; $time++) {
  echo date("H:00", mktime($time+1)).'<br>';
}
```

## EDIT:

Just for fun, here is another example

```
foreach(range(intval('07:00:00'),intval('16:00:00')) as $time) {
  echo date("H:00", mktime($time+1)).'<br>';
}
```

Comment: added :00 inside date to format it visually

Comment: what if on input i will have variables like this $start = "07:00:00" and $end="15:00:00" do I need to use strtodate() ? because i'm querying these variables from database... thanks...

Comment: You can create a valid hour as start/end from db time with $start = date("H", mktime('07:00:00')); $end = date("H", mktime('15:00:00')); Probably some simpler ways to do it aswell.

Comment: Added another example as edit

Answer (score 1):

```
$interval = date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 hour');
$begin = date_create('09:00');
$end = date_create('15:00')->add($interval);
foreach (new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end) as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format('H:i') . "\n";
}
```

**Demos:**

- https://eval.in/56289
- https://eval.in/56291
- https://eval.in/56292

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to `echo` the times you can do something simple like this:

```
$start_time = 9;
$end_time = 15;
for ($time = $start_time; $time <= $end_time; $time++) {
  if ($time < 10)
    echo "0";
  echo $time . ":00\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! the reason i have HH:MM:SS because this is how time stored in mySql database...

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_time = "15:49";
$hours = 9;

list($h, $m) = explode(':', $start_time);
while ($hours-->0)
{
    echo $h++ . ":" . $m . "\n";
}
```

Comment: wow that looks confusing :S